# BibTex (natbib) messing up citation order

Tags: natbib

I'm trying to use Natbib with squared numbers. However, in my text, the citations does not appear correctly. First when I tried it out, it numbered the citations correctly, so the first citation in the text would be named [ 1], and the second [2], and so forth. However, when I moved some text around, and the citations still kept their original numbers instead of automatically detecting which citation comes first.

To illustrate my problem:

[image: Problems with citation order]

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\begin{document}

This was once citation 2, but should be citatation 1, since it now appears first: \cite{pmid25348421}
This was once citation 1, but should be citation 2, since it currently appears second: \cite{pmid19995345}

\bibliography{Referencer}

\end{document}
```

I have tried to remove all the .aux files, and also scoured the internet for solutions, but all for naught.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `unsrtnat` instead of `abbrvnat`.

Comment: side note for the future: if you just want to force the bibliography to be updated, delete the `.bbl` file

Comment: switched to unsrtnat, and it works. Thanks for both your answers!

Answer (score 2):

The bibliography style you want is “unsorted”, that is, the bib items are listed in order of appearance. Thus you need

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

rather than `abbrvnat`.

Remember to rerun BibTeX after doing the change.